# Iframe translation – how do I create a dictionary with values and override text values

Tags: javascript, dictionary, iframe, language-translation

I'm trying to translate an iframe (Goorgias Live Chat) into other languages besides English (Portuguese, Italian and Spanish). This iframe has been implemented on a web store.

I've been told to prepare a dictionary with values from **Weglot.translate function** (https://developers.weglot.com/javascript/javascript-functions) and then pass it to the chat by overriding text values.

```
<script>
var dict = {
    "introductionText": "How can we help?",
    "offlineIntroductionText": "We'll be back tomorrow",
    "actionPostbackError": "An error occurred while processing your action. Please try again.",
    "clickToRetry": "Message not delivered. Click to retry.",
    "conversationTimestampHeaderFormat": "MMMM D",
    "fetchHistory": "Load more",
    "fetchingHistory": "Retrieving history...",
    "invalidFileError": "Only images are supported. Choose a file with a supported extension (jpg, jpeg, png, gif, or bmp).",
    "messageError": "An error occurred while sending your message. Please try again.",
    "messageIndicatorTitlePlural": "({count}) New messages",
    "messageIndicatorTitleSingular": "({count}) New message",
    "messageRelativeTimeDay": "{value}d ago",
    "messageRelativeTimeHour": "{value}h ago",
    "messageRelativeTimeJustNow": "Just now",
    "messageRelativeTimeMinute": "{value}m ago",
    "messageTimestampFormat": "h:mm A",
    "messageSending": "Sending...",
    "messageDelivered": "Delivered",
    "tapToRetry": "Message not delivered. Tap to retry.",
    "unsupportedMessageType": "Unsupported message type.",
    "unsupportedActionType": "Unsupported action type.",
    "headerText": "Gorgias Team",
    "inputPlaceholder": "Type a message...",
    "emailCapturePlaceholder": "your@email.com",
    "emailCaptureInputLabel": "Get notified by email",
    "emailCaptureOnlineTriggerText": "Leave us your email and we will reply soon.",
    "emailCaptureOnlineThanksText": "Thanks! We'll email you at {email} if you leave.",
    "emailCaptureOfflineTriggerText": "We're away, leave us your email and we'll respond shortly.",
    "emailCaptureOfflineThanksText": "Thanks {email}! We'll get back to you shortly.",
    "emailCaptureRequiredEmailPlaceholder": "Leave your email",
    "emailCaptureRequiredMessagePlaceholder": "Write your message",
    "backLabelBackInAMinute": "Back in 1 minute",
    "backLabelBackInMinutes": "Back in {value} minutes",
    "backLabelBackInAnHour": "Back in 1 hour",
    "backLabelBackInHours": "Back in {value} hours",
    "backLabelBackInDays": "Back in {value} days",
    "backLabelBackTomorrow": "Back tomorrow",
    "campaignClickToReply": "Click to reply",
    "poweredByGorgias": "Powered by Gorgias",
    "send": "Send"
}

var gorgiasChatInterval = window.setInterval(function() {
    if (window.GorgiasChat && GorgiasChat.hasOwnProperty("updateTexts")) {
      window.clearInterval(gorgiasChatInterval); // this line breaks out of the loop - make sure it's not deleted.
      window.GORGIAS_CHAT_TEXTS = dict
      GorgiasChat.updateTexts(dict)
    }
}, 100);
</script>
```

(this is the dictionary containing the chat texts)

How can I write this?

Thanks,
Carolina

Comment: What is the problem? Looks like you just change `"introductionText": "Comment pouvons nous aider?",` and so on

Comment: Right, but what I need is for the content to change according to the subdomain of the website. Let's say for fr.website.com we would have "introductionText": "Comment pouvons nous aider?" and for pt.website.com we would have "introductionText": "Como posso ajudar?" and so on. And I would need the content of the iframe to change depending on the subdomain we're at.

Comment: That is rather important missing information in your question.

Comment: Why not use the [built-in languages](https://updates.gorgias.com/posts/chat-internationalization)

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work with different subdomains, only with different domains.

Answer (score 0):

have a look at this

```js
const dicts = {
  "en": {
    "introductionText": "How can we help?",
    "offlineIntroductionText": "We'll be back tomorrow",
    "actionPostbackError": "An error occurred while processing your action. Please try again.",
    // ............
    "send": "Send"
  },
  "fr": {
    "introductionText": "Comment ....",
    "offlineIntroductionText": "Nous...",
    "actionPostbackError": "Un erreur ....",
    // ............
    "send": "Envoyer...."
  }
};
const url = new URL(location.href)
const lang = url.hostname.split(".")[0];
const dict = dicts[lang] || dicts["en"]; // take the english if no dict found for subdomain

console.log(dict)

/* here you have your gorgiasChatInterval code */
```

Comment: Here: const dict = dicts[lang] || dicts["en"]; should I add the other subdomains?

Comment: No. You add the others to `const dicts = { "en": {}, "fr": {}, "pt": {}}`  and if you need another default, change dicts["en"] to for example dicts["pt"] -  if you are happy with en as default, then my code works wihout you changing   `const dict = dicts[lang] || dicts["en"];`

Comment: I believe the iframe is not responding to the code – the translation is not occuring.

Comment: You removed the comments `/*` and `*/` I had in my code since I do not have GorgiasChat right?

Comment: I did remove the comments. Is there anything else I must keep from Gorgias or that I must change in their code?

Comment: Not if your English dict worked before

Comment: It did work: 
<script>
var dict = {
    "introductionText": "How can we help?",
(....)
"send": "Send"
}
when I had this. But with the new code not even the english dict is working when I apply changes to the values.

Comment: Then my code should work too if implemented  correctly

Comment: `var dict = { "introductionText"` will have the exact same result as `var dict =  dicts["en"];` where `dicts = { "en" : { "introductionText"`

Comment: @CarolinaAguiar So what is the problem? If you need to handle domain.com/fr, we can do that too